# How can I change Google Plus Custom URL?

Tags: google-plus

Today I set my Google Plus Custom URL but there is a mistake in the URL that I didn't notice until now.

Is there any way to change this URL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of now, it is impossible to change your Google+ Custom URL. The [Google support page](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2676340?hl=en) says:

> Once approved, this URL will be linked to your Google+ page or
>   Profile, so be sure everything is exactly the way you want it. Once
>   your URL has been approved, you can't request to change it. When
>   you're certain, click Confirm.
>
> **Change your custom URL**
>
> If you want to change the capitalization or accents/diacritics of your
>   custom URL, follow these steps:
>
> Go to the "Links" section of your Google+ profile. A box will appear
>   allowing you to make edits to the formatting. Remember, **you can only
>   change the capitalization or accents/diacritics of the URL, not the
>   URL itself.**

I guess you're not the only one having such an issue so Google might change this policy, but right now I believe there's nothing you can do.

Comment: It creates the name as per your internet web address. Thus, it added my domain extension to the name, which I don't want, meaning I can't take any part from it?

Answer (score 1):

No, **you can't do it now**. This has been a hard issue with Google+ and there is quite a possibility of change in this policy (as Google suggests). But, we have to wait till that change.